# How can I set an input field required using javascript or jquery in Gravity Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, gravity-forms-plugin

I am creating a registration form for an event using gravity forms. The form should allow the user to register if the number of participants is equal to the number shirts. If not, set the number of participants input field required.

Below there is a piece of code written by Faisal Ahammad which works, except when setting the field to required.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var participants = $('#input_1_36_1');
    var shirts = $('#input_1_18');
    var field = $('#field_1_45');

    function validateForm() {
        if (Number(participants.val()) !== Number(shirts.val())) {
            participants.attr('required', true);
            field.css('color', 'red');
            participants.css('border', '2px solid red');
            field.show();
        } else {
            field.css('color', 'green');
            field.hide();
               }
        }

     // Call validateForm every time the values of the input fields change
     participants.add(shirts).on('input', validateForm);

      validateForm();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use prop() instead of attr() for required attribute**

Replacing calls to attr () with prop () in your code will generally work. Properties are generally simpler to deal with than attributes. An attribute value may only be a string whereas a property can be of any type.

Here's an updated version of the code:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var participants = $('#input_1_36_1');
        var shirts = $('#input_1_18');
        var field = $('#field_1_45');
    
        function validateForm() {
            if (Number(participants.val()) != = Number(shirts.val())) {
                participants.prop(
                    'required',
                    true);  // Use prop() instead of attr() for required attribute
                field.css('color', 'red');
                participants.css('border', '2px solid red');
                field.show();
            } else {
                field.css('color', 'green');
                field.hide();
            }
        }
    
        // Call validateForm every time the values of the input fields change
        participants.add(shirts).on('input', validateForm);
    
        validateForm();
    });
```

Comment: Hi Prem, thanks for the help. I have tried to use prop() but still, it does not work.

Comment: Hi Sethu, Please can you provide the form HTML or the link to the form? that will be helpful in resolving the issue!